# Run shell script with external utility (plink) - unable to provide the context

Tags: bash, shell, unix, plink

I have a shell script in a Unix environment, which itself calls other scripts (which they call other scripts), that I want to call from Windows using the task scheduler. You can imagine something like this:

```
myMainScript.sh          (in /myFolder/myOtherFolder)
```

Inside this, I make calls like:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /myFolder/myOtherFolder       <-- this is to provide the context
cd otherSubFolder                <-- entering a subfolder
myOtherScript.sh                 <-- calling script in subfolder
```

Please note that `myOtherScript.sh` will also call other scripts, inside the same subfolder, which may eventually call other scripts and I can't modify those since they are "official" scripts I have no rights on.

When I run this script from a Shell console, everything works fine. 
When I run this script from `plink`, it raises me an error on the first command:

```
myOtherScript.sh: command not found
```

I hence tried to provide the absolute path, and instead of calling

```
myOtherScript.sh
```

... I call

```
/myFolder/myOtherFolder/otherSubFolder/myOtherScript.sh
```

In this case, the script is found and run, but then I have the same issue with the scripts which are called inside `myOtherScript.sh` (on which I have no modification rights).

I have also tried to put all the content of `myMainScript.sh` inside `pushd + popd` (providing the context `/myFolder/myOtherFolder`), but still no luck.

Can anyone lead me through the right direction?

P.s. just in case it helps, this is the way I call the script using `plink` (the call works, as I can read the logs of the command prompt showing that it's logged to the Unix environment):

```
"R:\tools\plink.exe" user@server-pw myPassword -sh -x "/myFolder/myOtherFolder/myMainScript.sh"
```

Comment: Have your main script `cd` in its own directory before calling the other scripts that rely on a specific working directory?

Comment: @Aaron yes, it's the very first command I launch.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ Have you got `.` in your `$PATH`? Have you tried `./myOtherScript.sh`?

Comment: Might be worth adding your main script to your question.

Comment: @Biffen that worked, I just needed to add the . in front of the path! If you write it as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: As an aside, the first `cd` doesn't do anything which introduces a "context". Switching to another directory immediately erases whatever "context" you were hoping for.